# Failed to record with get_iplayer for Windows

Tags: windows, virtualization, iplayer

I wonder if you can help me. I keep getting the under noted error message, no matter what I try to record. I have uninstalled and reinstalled but it makes no difference.

```
Recording The Following Programmes 
• http://www.bbc.co. uk/iplayer/episode/ bO lmfgsg/ EastEnders_28_08_20 12/ - - (http://www.bbc.co. uk/iplayer/episode/ bO 1 mf9s9/EastEnders_28_08_20 12/) 
INFO: Episode-only pid detected 
INFO: Trying pid: bOlmf9s9 using type: tv 
INFO Trying to stream pid using type tv 
INFO: pid not found in tv cache 
INFO: Checking existence of default version 
INFO: flashhighl,flastthigh2,flashstdl,flashstd2 modes will be tried for version default 
INFO: Trying flashhighl mode to record tv: EastEnders - 28/08/2012 
INFO: File name prefix = EastEnders_-_28_08_2012_bOlmf9s9_default 
WARNING: Your version of flvstreamer/rtmpdump does not support SWE Verification 
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade 
INFO: skipping flashhighl mode 
INFO: Trying flashhigh2 mode to record tv: EastEnders — 28/08/2012 
INFO: File name prefix = EastEnders_—_28_08_2012_bolmf9s9_default 
WARNING: Your version of flvstreamer/rtmpdump does not support SWF Verification 
WARNING: rtinpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade 
INFO: skipping flashhigh2 mode 
INFO: Trying flashstdl mode to record tv: EastEnders — 28/08/2012 
INFO: File name prefix = EastEnders_—_28_08_2012_bOlmf9s9_default 
WARNING: Your version of flvstreamer/rtmpdump does not support SWF Verification 
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required - please upgrade 
INFO: skipping flashstdl mode 
INFO: Trying flashstd2 mode to record tv: EastEnders — 28/08/2012 
INFO: File name prefix = EastEnders_—_2808_2012b01ff9s9_default 
WARNING: Your version of flvstreamer/rtmpdump does not support SWF Verification 
WARNING: rtmpdump/flvstreamer 1.8 or later is required — please upgrade 
INFO: skipping flashstd2 mode 
ERROR: Failed to record ‘EastEnders — 28/08/2012 (bOlmf9s9)’ 
Recording complete 
getjplayer Web PVR Manager v2.82, ©2009-2010 Phil Lewis - Licensed under GPLv3 
The details of my system are
Operating System 
Windows 7 Home Premium (x64) Service Pack 1 (build 7601)

Processor
3.60 gigahertz AMD FX-4100 Quad-Core
192 kilobyte primary memory cache
4096 kilobyte secondary memory cache
8192 kilobyte tertiary memory cache
64-bit ready
Multi-core (2 total)
Hyper-threaded (4 total)

Main Circuit Board
Board: ASUSTeK Computer INC. M5A78L-M LX V2 Rev X.0x
Serial Number: MF70C1G00603036
Bus Clock: 200 megahertz
BIOS: American Megatrends Inc. 0601 11/30/2011

8176 Megabytes Usable Installed Memory
```

I have installed **get_iplayer** on a Windows Vista 32bit virtual machine and on a Windows 7 32bit VM on the same computer and it works perfectly well.

Do you have any idea what is going on and how I can fix it? Any advice would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

After Phil Lewis dropped development, a few forks of get_iplayer appeared so you might be using a not so good/up-to-date one.

Try completely uninstalling and then installing using this [link from infradead.org](http://www.infradead.org/get_iplayer_win/get_iplayer_setup_latest.exe)

I suggest this because looking at the output, it doesn't actually appear to be hitting an error per se, it's just recognising a limitation of software you have installed. Software which get_iplayer installed for you specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you got this issue sorted, looks like it is a question of updating as the other commenter said.

I have written a quite comprehensive beginners guide to get_iPlayer which might be of use to others who find this post, or even you if you are still having trouble. You can find it here:

http://squarepenguin.co.uk/get_iplayer-guide-for-beginners/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.